# Return all characters but the first X amount Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a long list of codes and text in the same cell. I need to return all the text from the right BUT the first five characters

ex. V2341 something here

I need to return the something here

```
=RIGHT(LEN(A1)-5)
```

That's what I've tried, but no luck with it.  I know it's gotta be close to correct, what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: solved it.  here's how i did it.  =RIGHT(A1,C1-5) where c1 is =length of A1.

Comment: =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-5) would have worked also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `MID`.

If column A contains

```
    A                          C                         D
    ====================       ======================    ==============
1   ABCDE12345                 D1=MID(A1, 6, LEN(A1))    12345
2   ABCDE1234567890ABCD        D2=MID(A2, 6, LEN(A2))    1234567890ABCD
```

Answer (score 2):

REPLACE function can also be used to replace a designated number of characters with nothing, i.e.

`=REPLACE(A1,1,5,"")`

Answer (score 1):

You can also select the whole column, use ctrl+f, then find and replace the 'v' with nothing. This will work easily if you have the same first amounts you are trying to get rid of.

If you are trying to get rid of the same number of characters, but they are different characters, you can go to Data -> Text to Columns (in Data Tools Sections). Then select the radio button fixed width. Click Next. Move the line in the graphic to the position you want it in, click Finish.